# Анимация при скролле progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Анимация должна срабатывать, когда я скроллом дойду до нужного блока. Подскажите, как реализовать ?

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

// Функция, которая 
var visible = function(e) {
  var elementTop = window.pageYOffset + e.getBoundingClientRect().top, // Получаем координаты верхней части элементы
      windowBottom = window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight; // Получаем положение нижней части окна
  
  // Если положение нижней части окна больше чем верхняя координата элемента, то мы долистали до элемента
  // Так же проверим, не запущена ли уже анимация, а то выйдет казус в виде всё время запускающееся анимации
  if(elementTop < windowBottom && Number(e.dataset.animationState) === 0){
    bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
    
    e.dataset.animationState = 1; // Отмечаем, что анимация запущена
  };
};

// Получаем нужный элемент
var element = document.querySelector('#container');

// Запускаем функцию
// Запускаем при скролле
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  visible(element);
});

// И сразу при загрузке страницы. Вдруг элемент уже находится в видимой области
visible(element);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>

<div id="container" data-animation-state="0"></div>
```

<sup>ассоциация: [Как определить что элемент в зоне видимости окна браузера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641531/)</sup>