# Как заставить сработать условие?

Tags: javascript, css

Всем добрый вечер.
 В шапке есть логотип, который после прелодера должен анимировано показываться, но если по какой-то причине пользователь открыл сайт не с шапки и доскролил до этого места, должна пройти анимация. То есть `setTimeOut` тут не подойдет. Пытался и в функцию выносить, лучше не стало, есть идеи как это реализовать?
PS Сама анимация сделана на `CSS` с помощью `translate` и `transition`. 
 Хочу сделать на чистом JS

```
let el = document.querySelector('.el');
el.classList.add('animate');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let bottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if (bottom >= 0) {
        el.classList.remove('animate');
    }
});
```

Сейчас код выглядит вот так

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать анимацию только когда элемент видит пользователь. Примерно как тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641531/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @Lukas спасибо за наводку, с этим можно поиграться :)