# Навигация js как сделать

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется большой ***landing page***, разбитый на **блоки**.

Каждый блок находится в теге `section` у каждого **блока** имеется ***id `<section id="section1">`***, а также на странице имеется навигация `<a href="#section1">`. По нажатии на ссылку в навигации, пользователь переходит к нужному **блоку**.

Идея такова, пользователь заходит на сайт, листает страницу  вниз ***не задействуя навигацию*** и в реальном времени подсвечивается нужный пункт навигации.

> Например, пользователь в данный момент видит блок с ***id="hello"***,
>   в навигации подсвечивается

Есть какой нибудь `js или jquery` скрипт ***на Github, например***, который определяет, какой блок сейчас видит пользователь.

Не судите строго, первый мой вопрос.

Comment: fullPage.js, при условии, что блок занимает весь экран. Больше и не вспомню((

Comment: Не нужны тебе никакие сторонние либы. Почитай про координаты в окне. Это не сложная задача. Вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates) можешь почитать подробнее.

Comment: @Air: что за самодеятельность, зачем столько болда и чем вам помешали авторские скобки? Достаточно было ограничиться выделением кода в ``

Comment: Посмотри как [тут реализовано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641531/Как-определить-что-элемент-в-зоне-видимости-окна-браузера)

Comment: @Kromster, что именно помешал....???

Comment: @Air 1 - вы заменили кавычки на болд, тем самым изменив смысл с "условного" на акцентный. Было *"у меня есть некий "landing page", разбитый на условные "блоки"."*, вы же сделали непонятный акцент - *"у меня есть LANDING PAGE, разбитый на условные БЛОКИ."*. Сделали это многократно, превратив текст в винегрет. 2 - то что код выделили в `` это хорошо, но зачем-то и его раскрасили в болд и италик - опять ненужное украшательство.

Comment: @Kromster, А мне кажется, я прекрасно правил вопрос...

Comment: @Air я художник, я так вижу :D.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну да... Прям в точку...))))))